# How to search for a string with "+" character in sed?

Tags: sed

I want to search for `S+P` and replace it with `S&P`.  Following doesn't seem to be working.

```
sed 's~"S+P"~"S&P"~' filename1 > filename2
```

Comment: @don_crissti I am aware of this page but that doesn't seem to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is metacharacter and should be escaped for literal matching. Within `sed` replacement section `&` points to the whole matched string (in your example, `&` represents the whole `S+P`):

```
sed 's~S+P~S\&P~g' file
```

Comment: Thank you that helps.  I am now trying to add this two pattern combinations as pipe delimited in a file and reading it from there to replace. But running into similar issue.

Comment: while read PatternToReplace
            do
                origPattern=`echo "$PatternToReplace" | sed 's/|/:/' | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'`
                newPattern=`echo $PatternToReplace | sed 's/|/:/' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'`
                sed 's~'"$origPattern"'~'"$newPattern"'~' /tmp/aspgpcf > /tmp/new_aspgpcf
                mv /tmp/new_aspgpcf /tmp/aspgpcf
            done < PatternReplacement